# Live reload when code changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible to have asp.net core applications to reload in the browser when there are code changes made?

I am running things using the command-line:

```
dotnet run
```

It is annoying to have to control-c to stop and then start the app each time.

Comment: yes it is. now ask your question that respects SO's guidelines for asking questions.

Comment: You can edit .aspx files and refresh your browser just fine.  When you edit .cs files, that's when you need to rebuild.  .NET is a compiled language, it'sn ot like PHP or node...

Comment: @Kyle There are no aspx files in ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 3):

Google "dotnet watch".  It's a MS tool that let's you fire off commands when your source code changes (like, recompiling your code without stopping and restarting manually).  Very useful and is likely exactly what you're looking for.

https://jonhilton.net/2016/08/04/compile-your-changes-on-the-fly-with-net-core/